# Update marker in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have a problem with a marker in leaflet. My code is this:

```
var updateMarker = function(lat, lng) {
    if($('.leaflet-marker-icon').length)
        marker.setLatLng([lat, lng]);
    else
        var marker = L.marker([lat, lng]).addTo(map);
    return false;
};
var updateMarkerByInputs = function() {
    return updateMarker( $('#latInput').val() , $('#lngInput').val());
}
$('#latInput').on('input', updateMarkerByInputs);
$('#lngInput').on('input', updateMarkerByInputs);

map.on('click', function(e) {
    $('#latInput').val(e.latlng.lat);
    $('#lngInput').val(e.latlng.lng);
    updateMarker(e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng);
});
```

As you can see, on the first click will be add a marker and in the next clicks it should be updated. But I get this error at the second click:

```
TypeError: i is undefined
    ..."_leaflet_id";return function(i){return i[e]=i[e]||++t,i[e]}}(),invokeEach:funct...
leaflet.js (line 6, col 603)
```

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are defining your `marker` variable locally in the `updateMarker` function, so the reference is lost as soon as the function returns.

Define it outside the function:

```
var marker;

var updateMarker = function(lat, lng) {
    if($('.leaflet-marker-icon').length)
        marker.setLatLng([lat, lng]);
    else
        marker = L.marker([lat, lng]).addTo(map);
    return false;
};
```

This way you don't need to check the DOM with jQuery to find out if your marker is defined, you can check directly the marker variable:

```
var marker;

var updateMarker = function(lat, lng) {
    if (marker) {
        marker.setLatLng([lat, lng]);
    } else {
        marker = L.marker([lat, lng]).addTo(map);
    }
    return false;
};
```

(to improve readability I would suggest to always use brackets in your `if` statements.)